# How to display dropdown in mat-table and then display other columns based on dropdown selected option in typescript?

Tags: angular

Suppose this is my api response-

I need to assign followUpLists to FollowList array using for loop? how can i code the for loop in typescript?

```
{
  "Info": [
    {
      "CustomerId": "3",
      "CustomerName": "Sreejesh Panayappilly ",
      "followUpLists": [
        {
          "CustomerId": "3",
          "CustomerName": "Sreejesh Panayappilly ",
          "ProductName": "OLT - GPON - V1600G0 - 4 PON PORT",
          "MacId": "14A72BA2AFF2",
          "AMCStartDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "AMCEndDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "AMCStatus": 1,
          "FollowStatus": 0
        },
        {
          "CustomerId": "3",
          "CustomerName": "Sreejesh Panayappilly ",
          "ProductName": "OLT - GPON - V1600G1 (B) - 8 PON PORT",
          "MacId": "14A72BF09C40",
          "AMCStartDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "AMCEndDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "AMCStatus": 1,
          "FollowStatus": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "CustomerId": "5",
      "CustomerName": "Priyamvadan",
      "followUpLists": [
        {
          "CustomerId": "5",
          "CustomerName": "Priyamvadan",
          "ProductName": "OLT - GPON - V1600G1 (B) - 8 PON PORT",
          "MacId": "14A72BF09B8C",
          "AMCStartDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "AMCEndDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "AMCStatus": 1,
          "FollowStatus": 1
        }
      ]
    },
 ],
  "Status": true,
  "Message": "Data Collected Successfully."
}
```

I need to assign followUpLists array to FollowList array using for loop? how can i code the for loop in typescript?

Comment: Please provide code from what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try :

```
const FollowList = [];
yourObject.Info.map(e => FollowList.push(...e.followUpLists));
```